# Java 8, why not a ZonedTime class?

Tags: date, datetime, time, timezone, java-8

I found that Java 8 doesn't have an equivalent to [ZonedDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) but to work only with **Time** (a *ZonedTime* class or something like that). **I know** they included the [OffsetTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html) class, but it only stores the offset.

Storing time zones along with date and time, instead of just store the offset, helps to deal with daylight savings easier.

I'm not asking you to give me alternatives, I know there are many approaches; I'm just wondering why such class was not included, is it a design issue? or they just found it to be redundant?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You say "Java 8 doesn't have an equivalent to ZonedDateTime" while including a link to the very Java 8 doc that defines that ZonedDateTime class bundled in Java 8.

Comment: I accept that maybe my question was not well formulated, but I think it's still valid. I think the most of the people got the point.

Comment: Upon a third reading it seems your quest is for a class defining a time-of-day-only value without any date yet having an offset from UTC or even a time zone. As the [accepted answer by Meno Hochschild](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26541249/642706) correctly states, that may seem intuitively like a good idea but is problematic. Time zones and offsets are redefined because of politics and borders, Daylight Saving Time, and other anomalies. Without a date, the time zone has no specific meaning.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Introducing a class `ZonedTime` consisting of `LocalTime` and a time zone (instead of a simple offset) would be a heavy mistake.

The suggested type does not contain a date. But without a date it will not be possible to evaluate the real timezone offset to map the local time to any sensible global time. For taking into account any daylight saving aspects you must have as well a date and a time.

Comment: I had actually thought of that before, but I think it'd be useful in some cases. Anyways, thanks for the response. I would use it, for example, to store the time of a school schedule; I'm not going to perform conversions on which the date is important, I just want to know what time the class starts and ends to show it to users in other parts of the world.

Comment: @JuanLhc For showing class start and end times to people in another part of the world, you'll still need to know the date. Otherwise it will be impossible to determine the difference in offsets, given that you cannot know whether the summer time or winter time offset is to be used.

Comment: You are completely right. Thanks for your response!

Comment: -1 I find this answer unconvincing. Simply saying you can't map it to the right date by itself does not mean there is no use case for this type. I support an application where an event must happen everyday on a given time in a location (i.e. every day 1 PM in London). 5 PM NY is a heavily used concept in financial systems. A ZonedTime is a logical type for this problem - the date can be provided on evaluation of the function.

Comment: @firtydank Or you can simply manage and pass two parameters, one for the clock time and one for the time zone. Both are not independent from each other and not correlated at all. A single combination type is not necessary for your scenario IMHO and should require more justification than just avoiding two parameters.

Comment: @Meno Of course, there are many ways to solve this, but that does not make such a type a "heavy mistake".

Comment: @firtydank I agree with @Meno. Most people think of daily recurring tasks as being within a timezone regardless of daylight savings. JuanLhc 's example of class start time being a prime example. To get the precise time for any given day, it would have a `toZonedDateTime(LocalDate date)` method. I create many processes that I want to run at the same time (ex 8pm) every day, and I shouldn't have to create my own classes to combine a time & timezone. A full "time" library (like java.time) should include this.

Comment: @John I'm finding this line of reasoning quite bizarre. OO provides for multiple correct strategies to solve problems. To call one valid strategy a "heavy mistake" is strange. To say "it has no value because I can work around it" is even stranger. There are many types in the world that you don't need but are useful.

Comment: @firtydank OOPS!  I got the names mixed up.  My comment and line of reasoning agrees with you and disagrees with Meno. I also believe calling it a "Heavy Mistake" to be strange. There ought to be a ZonedTime class.  I don't think I can fix my comment now, so ...  sorry!