# Parsing date with timezone from a string

Tags: java, date, java-time, datetimeoffset

Quick (I suppose) question. How to parse string like that `"2018-07-22 +3:00"` to `OffsetDateTime` (setting time to `0:0:0.0`)?

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =cDateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd xxx");
OffsetDateTime dt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2007-07-21 +00:00", formatter);
```

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2007-07-21 +00:00'
>   could not be parsed: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from
>   TemporalAccessor: {OffsetSeconds=0},ISO resolved to 2007-07-21 of type
>   java.time.format.Parsed

Comment: [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), e.g. using [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Comment: Well, I did, of course. Ok, will add, but it's not working

Comment: @Andreas I added what I did, and how could it help?

Comment: Your question text shows `+3:00`, which is an invalid offset since hour is only 1 digit, but your code shows `+00:00` with 2-digit hour. Do you need to parse 1-digit hour or not?

Comment: @Andreas I'd like to parse both 1 and 2 digits variants, of course

Comment: Come on, guys, what's wrong with you? Why downvote???

Comment: Downvotes might be because these issues have been handled many times on Stack Overflow already. Or perhaps because a date with an offset makes no sense without a time of day.

Comment: @BasilBourque would you mind to show me where exactly this issue is mentioned? I didn’t find any. Regarding date - if no time specified explicitly, it shall be set to 0, as I wrote in the question.

Comment: @BbIKTOP [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34810324). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26538102). And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32383495).

Comment: @BasilBourque lol, don't you see a difference? You could also show any other random questions )))) Well, I've got the answer, thanks these guys who helped me. Maybe it will be useful for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `OffsetDateTime` requires a time-of-day, but your format string doesn't supply that, so you need to tell the `DateTimeFormatter` to default time-of-day to midnight.

Also, offset `+3:00` is invalid, since hour must be 2-digit, which means you need to fix that first.

This will do both:

```
public static OffsetDateTime parse(String text) {
    // Fix 1-digit offset hour
    String s = text.replaceFirst("( [+-])(\\d:\\d\\d)$", "$10$2");

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("uuuu-MM-dd xxx")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
            .toFormatter();
    return OffsetDateTime.parse(s, formatter);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(parse("2018-07-22 +3:00"));
System.out.println(parse("2018-07-22 +03:00"));
System.out.println(parse("2007-07-21 +00:00"));
```

*Output*

```
2018-07-22T00:00+03:00
2018-07-22T00:00+03:00
2007-07-21T00:00Z
```

Comment: Yes, I know that DateTimeFormatter does not accept single digit hours in offset, just wonder why. Actually, in my real case might be more variants, so regex is not good to use. But it doesn't matter, I can just throw an exception in this case, no problem.

Thank you, it shall be working, but getting TemporalAccessor then extracting date, time and timezone is simpler and more universal - it's possible to check is there date, time and timezone supplied, and set defaults accordingly, if necessary.

Comment: @BbIKTOP Using regex *is* a good way for fixing bad input, but not necessarily *that* particular regex pattern if you need to support other offset formats. --- Why would *you* need to throw exception? `parse` method already does if input is invalid.

Comment: I do not know the exact format of the input string, so, I'm checking against the set of DateTimeFormatters catching exceptions, and this particular case was the problem. Tried DateTimeFormattersBuilder#append but didn't succeed. I'd like to support at least the whole predefined set of formatters and don't want to duplicate these formatters with regexes. Actually, I started with regex, but then switched to the predefined parsers and exceptions handling. So, yes, it surely throws an exception and I will throw it further. Let these clients suffer from java as well! )))

Comment: From Java 9, you can use DateTimeFormatterBuilder to parse single digit hours in offsets. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOffset-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 4):

The trick here is to start by getting the `TemporalAccessor`:

```
TemporalAccessor ta = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd XXX").parse("2018-07-22 +03:00");
```

From there, you can extract a `LocalDate` and a `ZoneOffset`:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.from(ta);
ZoneOffset tz = ZoneOffset.from(ta);
```

And combine them like so:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = date.atStartOfDay(tz);
```

Comment: Yes,will try, but it looks like it's what I need, thank you.